# I need to create a class instance by triggering a Button widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I can instantiate the class fine now, but I have no way to reference the object that is created.

This button calls a function that takes a variable as an argument.

```
self.gencharbutton = Button(self.topleftframe, text='8: Generate Character!', command=lambda: self.createcharacterobject(self.racevar.get()))
```

If I were to create this object in a script I would do something like this:

```
character = self.createcharacterobject(self.racevar.get()))
```

and then I could reference the object and its attributes like this:

```
character.name
```

or

```
character.height
```

Given the fact that I can not put an assignment statement in the Button, how do I reference this object?

I'm sorry, but I am still getting a grip on OOP, so the answer may be fairly obvious to other folks. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You don't have to cram a Button's entire action into a lambda - you can just as easily set the `command=` option to the name of a function or method that can do whatever you need, using however many statements it takes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Jason. That is true. I have tried it without the lambda as well and it still will not accept an assignment statement. 

The function in my example runs an if,elif, else statement that decides exactly which class it will instantiate. Within that function I have the instance assigned to self.character, then I return that variable. but without an assignment in the class itself, I can't reference the returned class object itself.

Comment: Don't use lambda. Call a function. In that function you can easily assign variables.

Comment: There's no point in including a `return` value in the function, as Tkinter is just going to ignore it.  The function needs to do whatever needs to be done with the value itself, or at least store it somewhere that's visible to other code of yours.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley

This gets to the heart of my problem. I have assigned the variable to the object like this: 

self.character = classlibrary.Cleric(various arguments)

The object is created because I can print(self.character) to console within the function, but I cannot print it or access it in any way outside of that function, I assume because it loses the association to "self.character" outside of the function.

I assume that prepending "self" to character, would make the variable accessible to the outer scope (object that represents my gui) that my function is nested in, but it is not

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. If you assign something to `self.character`, there is no way it can "lose the association".

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite an old question but this is what I did with a similar case (though I just started learning programming and python like 1 months ago, during my commute to work)

```
from tkinter import *

class Character:
    def __init__(self,race):
        self.race=race

def createCharacter():
    charname=field1.get()
    chlst.insert(0,charname)
    text=("global "+chlst[0]+"\n"+chlst[0]+"=Character('"+racevar.get()+"')")
    exec(text)

chlst=[]
root=Tk()
field1=Entry(root)
field1.pack()
racevar=Entry(root)
racevar.pack()
butt1=Button(root,text="Create",command=createCharacter)
butt1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

So basically I get the name from an entry widget and store it in a list, so that later I can get it when needed.
The one thing I missed for a lot of time is to declare `"global "+chlst[0]+"\n"` in my text that is executed later.